Unit testing a Web Worker in JavaScript/TypeScript - Best Practice
I got assigned with writing unit tests for a class that instantiate a Worker inside in it's constructor. The code looks simmilar to this,
class SomeClass {
  private _worker: Worker;
  constructor(flag: number) {
    this._worker = this.createWorker(flag);
    this.onmessage();
  }

  private createWorker(flag: number) {
    switch (flag) {
      case 1:
        return new Worker('possibly different url');

      case 2:
        return new Worker('possibly different url');

      default:
        return new Worker('possibly different url');
    }
  }

  private onmessage() {
    this._worker.onmessage = () => {
      this.somefunction();
    };
  }
  private somefunction() {
    //some code
  }
}

To test this, I tried implementing a FakeWorker class and assigned this definition into window.Worker attribute by using the following code in beforeAll and afterAll
/*before all*/
actualWorkerDefinition=window.Worker
window.Worker=FakeWorker

/*after all*/
window.Worker=ActualWorkerDefinition

This helped me write the test cases for SomeClass without any issue. My question is: Is overriding window.Worker considered bad practice?
One of my team members also suggested that I can use an iframe instead of this approch and create the actual worker using that. That is a bit cumbersome for a unit test and will require linking actual js file in the project that has no relationship to this code. Would like to know your opinion on this approach as well.
Would also like to know whether there are some alternative approaches to this.

What you are doing is something I've done many times before. Not with web workers, but with other kinds of things like XMLHttpRequest. JavaScript is flexible like that. You could keep it as is. While I think an <iframe> would give you better isolation, it is entirely unnecessary. Unit tests in the browser run one at a time because JavaScript is single-threaded. Overwriting the window.Worker property would only be a problem if you could run these tests in parallel, which is not currently possible.
I think you could alleviate your coworker's concerns and simplify testing by using proper dependency injection in your system under test:
constructor(flagOrWorker: number | Worker) {
    if (flagOrWorker instanceof Worker) {
        this._worker = (Worker)flagOrWorker;
    }
    else {
        this._worker = this.createWorker((number)flagOrWorker);
    }
}

By passing in your own Worker object to new SomeClass(...) you can provide your own stub or fake. This is actually where TypeScript becomes a pain. I bet TypeScript will think of Worker as a class rather than an interface. If you have plain old JavaScript, you could just use the silly thing, so maybe numberOrWorker could be an any type instead:
constructor(flagOrWorker: any) {
    if (flagOrWorker instanceof Worker) {
        this._worker = (Worker)flagOrWorker;
    }
    else {
        this._worker = this.createWorker((number)flagOrWorker);
    }
}

Another alternative design would be to settle on a Worker object as a constructor param, and expose a static factory method:
class SomeClass {
    constructor(worker: Worker) {
        this._worker = worker;
    }

    static create(flag: number): SomeClass {
        return new SomeClass(SomeClass.createWorker(flag));
    }

    static createWorker(flag: number): Worker {
        // switch based on flag
    }
}

In your production code, you can call SomeClass.create(3). Your unit tests can initialize SomeClass directly, passing in a stub worker. You could also consider creating an interface for the Worker class that SomeClass would consume. TypeScript will allow you to pass an object that supports an interface by coincidence. You don't necessarily need a TypeScript definition for the native Worker class provided your own custom interface contains the same methods and properties.
After utilizing proper dependency injection, you get: new SomeClass(new FakeWorker()) — now you don't need to overwrite native browser features and restore them, or juggle awkward <iframe>s.

Thank you for your well thought out response, you managed to address all my concerns . And yes you're right, Typescript does think worker as a class instead of an interface. Currently I don't have the authority to change the production code. So I think I'll stick with FakeWorker class since you already told that it is harmless. That said, I also think that your DI solution is the better approach and will use it in my future projects. Cheers!!
